# Let $m$ and $n$ be integers such that $\gcd (m, n) = 1$. Show that $\gcd (m + n, m - n) = 1$ or $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let m and n be integers such that $\gcd (m, n) = 1$. Show that
$\gcd(m + n, m - n) = 1$ or $2$

Comment: Does this https://qr.ae/pN0VUK help you

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

If $d$ divides $a$ and $d$ divides $b$

then $d$ divides both $(a+b)$ and $(a - b).$